# Queries On Sys Schema Throws Empty Results On Aurora

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

my goal building queries related with sys schema, like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.host_summary_by_statement_type;
```

Is to get some stadistics and group them to show to my final clients as a security requeriment. I got same results with other queries that uses sys, and it is weird because on my local server it works but when I connect to my Aurora RDS always throws empty results.

Is there any kind of restriction from Amazon related with this? If so, Is there a way to remove the restriction?

Thanks in advance, good day.

Comment: Is the sys schema actually installed on your RDS MySQL instance? You may need to run a script to create it first.

Comment: But how do Aurora RDS CloudWatch to show those stadistics? Even with WorkBench Dashboard shows it too, I wanna do the same but by own, I had successful result showing DB connections (information_schema_processlist), for example: 

    SELECT count(ID) connections FROM information_schema.processlist

Comment: Check the parameter group for your Aurora instance - is `performance_schema` set to `1`? If not, the performance schema (and sys schema) is not set up so that could be why you don't see any data. Change this parameter to `1` and restart the instance and see if you start getting performance data.

Comment: Got it! I gonna check that, thank you :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, can you post your answer in order to check it as the correct one?

Comment: OK, re-worded this and added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys` schema for performance data does not exist by default for Aurora MySQL instances, you need to [enable it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html#USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.Console.Modifying).

Check the RDS [parameter group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) for your Aurora instance to see if the `performance_schema` parameter is set to `1`. If not, the performance schema (and sys schema) is not enabled so you won't see any data.

Change this parameter value to `1` and restart the instance, you should then start seeing performance data returned from views in this schema.